# How to extract numbers from a string using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parsing

I have a string:

`@string='TEST RESULTS\TEST 1\RESULT 1`

The string/text remains the same except for the numbers

1. need the 1 from TEST
2. need 1 from RESULT

to be used in a query like:

```
SET @sql =  "SELECT *
            FROM   TABLE
            WHERE  test = (expression FOR CASE 1 resulting IN INT 1)
                   AND result = (expression FOR CASE 2 resulting IN INT 1)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stable text and only 2 elements, you can make good use of [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) and [parsename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'TEST RESULTS\TEST 1\RESULT 2'

select cast(parsename(replace(replace(@string, 'TEST RESULTS\TEST ', ''), '\RESULT ', '.'), 2) as int) as Test
    , cast(parsename(replace(replace(@string, 'TEST RESULTS\TEST ', ''), '\RESULT ', '.'), 1) as int) as Result

/*
       Test      Result
----------- -----------
          1           2
*/
```

The replace portion does assume the same text and spacing always, and sets up for parsename with the period.

Comment: Thanks Tim, was able to get results as expected.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you already have a solution that met your needs but I have a little trick that I use to extract numbers from strings that I thought might benefit someone. It takes advantage of the FOR XML statement and avoids explicit loops. It makes a good inline table function or simple scalar. Do with it what you will :)

```
DECLARE @String varchar(255) = 'This1 Is2 my3 Test4 For Number5 Extr@ct10n';


SELECT
    CAST(( 
        SELECT CASE --// skips alpha. make sure comparison is done on upper case
            WHEN ( ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@String, Number, 1))) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 )
            THEN SUBSTRING(@String, Number, 1)
            ELSE ''END
        FROM
        ( 
            SELECT TOP 255 --// east way to get a list of numbers
                                           --// change value as needed.
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) AS Number
             FROM master.sys.all_columns a
                CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns b 
        ) AS n
        WHERE Number <= LEN(@String)
        --// use xml path to pivot the results to a row
        FOR XML PATH('') ) AS varchar(255)) AS Result
```

Result ==> 1234510

Comment: It's going to take a bit for me to get my head around exactly how this is working but it helped me out tonight and I appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can script an sql function which can used through your search queries.
Here is the sample code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_extractInteger(@string VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
    AS

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @count int
        DECLARE @intNumbers VARCHAR(1000)
        SET @count = 0
        SET @intNumbers = ''

        WHILE @count <= LEN(@string)
        BEGIN 
            IF SUBSTRING(@string, @count, 1)>='0' and SUBSTRING (@string, @count, 1) <='9'
                BEGIN
                    SET @intNumbers = @intNumbers + SUBSTRING (@string, @count, 1)
                END
            SET @count = @count + 1
        END
        RETURN @intNumbers
    END
    GO
```

QUERY :

```
SELECT dbo.udf_extractInteger('hello 123 world456') As output
```

OUTPUT:
123456

Referred from : http://www.ittutorials.in/source/sql/sql-function-to-extract-only-numbers-from-string.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `SUBSTRING`, `PARSENAME`, and `PATINDEX`:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(c,2), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',PARSENAME(c,2)), LEN(c)) Test,
  SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(c,1), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',PARSENAME(c,1)), LEN(c)) Result
FROM (   SELECT REPLACE(@val, '\', '.') c) t
```

Use `PARSENAME` to split the string.  The text of the string won't matter -- it will just need to contain the 2 back slashes to parse to 3 elements.  Use `PATINDEX` with a regular expression to replace non-numeric values from the result.  This would need adjusting if the text in front of the number ever contained numbers.

If needed, CAST/CONVERT the results to int or the appropriate data type.

Here is some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8480).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Sgeddes really appreciate your explaining how the expression works.

Comment: @Rodricks -- np, glad we could help.  I like this method as it doesn't require hard coding values in.  Best of luck.