# Do multiplications contained in text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to do the multiplications contained in a varchar field? (for the area in this case)

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                    DESCRIPTION                       |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|Thermal plate 605x745 Speed Chemfree                  |
|Thermal plate 665 X 910 Ryobi Fuji                    |
|Conventional Plate P 4001 605x745 Speed IBF           |
|Thermal plate 665 X 910 X 030 raw Ryobii IBF          |
|Thermal plate 800x1030 Komori Chemfree                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Okay, looking for an alternative solution to the problem, I noticed that there is a field with a short description containing the measures of the plates:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     CODE     |                    DESCRIPTION                       |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| T605745SPCHE |        Thermal plate 605x745 Speed Chemfree          |
| T665910RYJUF |        Thermal plate 665 X 910 Ryobi Fuji            |
| C605745SPIBF |        Conventional Plate P 4001 605x745 Speed IBF   |
| T665910RYIBF |        Thermal plate 665 X 910 X 030 raw Ryobii IBF  |
| T8001030KBF  |        Thermal plate 800x1030 Komori Chemfree        |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think my only problem now is how to treat the results with 7 numbers and not just 6. Some suggestions? containing the measures of the plates.

Comment: You are doing this all using only SQL?

Comment: I can use Crystal Reports with Visual Studio too.. But now I'm using only SQL.

Comment: Other than what is probably a non-exhaustive set of examples, do you have explicit rules what should and should not be considered eligible for multiplication? Can you think of examples that would fit the rules but shouldn't be multiplied (ex: a product name that happened to have a number, an 'x', and another number, like 'Super 4x4 Widget 101 x 202 Speed')?

Comment: Well, I would approach it by scanning each line. As soon as I found a digit, I'd get all constitutive digits and store the value at the first non digit. I'd then see if the next character (ignoring any spaces) is an X, and if so, I'd continue to do the same thing on the line. This would take me maybe 10 minutes in C#. SQL would take me longer.

Comment: I tried to post all kind of results. All multiplications that need to be made contains an "x" in the middle (sometimes with "space" separating, sometimes not). If the field has a third multiplier number, it will be disregarded. Sometimes results also appear terminated with a number, which are also negligible.

Comment: @JonathanWood, unfortunately my knowledge in C # (I'm studying it) are much lower than in SQL. I know treat a TextBox that way, but not a set of results from a database that would later be sent to the Crystal Reports. For now I'll keep me in my comfort zone while not mastered the new language.

Comment: This question answers part of what you're asking, and the rest of what you're asking would be done similarly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700214/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-using-tsql

Comment: How many records?  Is this a one time task (I expect so)?

Comment: A lot of records and lot of tasks.. hehe

Answer (score 0):

While I know this can be done purely in SQL, it would be somewhat unusual to do a task like this without using another language.

I think I'll go ahead and post some C# code to do this. I know it's not what you were asking for, but I'll post it anyway since it might be helpful in seeing how the task might be approached. Also, it might be helpful since you indicated you are learning C#.

```
void Main()
{
    string[] lines = {
        "+------------------------------------------------------+",
        "|                    DESCRIPTION                       |",
        "+------------------------------------------------------+",
        "|Thermal plate 605x745 Speed Chemfree                  |",
        "|Thermal plate 665 X 910 Ryobi Fuji                    |",
        "|Conventional Plate P 4001 605x745 Speed IBF           |",
        "|Thermal plate 665 X 910 X 030 raw Ryobii IBF          |",
        "|Thermal plate 800x1030 Komori Chemfree                |",
        "+------------------------------------------------------+"
    };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ProcessLine(line));
    }
}

int ProcessLine(string s)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool hasFirstValue = false;
    int pos = 0;

    while (pos < s.Length)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(s[pos]))
        {
            int i = ProcessNumber(s, ref pos);
            if (hasFirstValue)
                result *= i;
            else
            {
                result = i;
                hasFirstValue = true;
            }
            SkipWhitespace(s, ref pos);
            if (pos >= s.Length || Char.ToLower(s[pos]) != 'x')
                break;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return result;
}

int ProcessNumber(string s, ref int pos)
{
    int value = 0;
    while (pos < s.Length && Char.IsDigit(s[pos]))
    {
        value = (value * 10) + (s[pos] - '0');
        pos++;
    }
    return value;
}

void SkipWhitespace(string s, ref int pos)
{
    while (pos < s.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[pos]))
        pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whell, with this new Columnm things now are so more easy.
I did this:

```
'area' = (CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,2,3))*

        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,8,1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN
            CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,5,4)) ELSE
            CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,5,3)) END)/1000000
```

The `CONVERT` and `/1000000` are just for unit convertion.

Thank you all!